# Pip Package is not Installing on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, odoo, pypi

I have tried installing [this](https://pypi.org/project/odoo11-addon-web-tree-dynamic-colored-field/) pip package for python 3 
But I receive this error:

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement odoo<11.1dev,>=11.0a (from odoo11-addon-web-tree-dynamic-colored-field) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for odoo<11.1dev,>=11.0a (from odoo11-addon-web-tree-dynamic-colored-field)
```

If I download the `whl` package and try to install, I receive this error:

```
`odoo10_addon_web_tree_dynamic_colored_field-10.0.1.0.0-py2-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platfo`rm.
```

How can I resolve these errors and install the pip package?

Answer (score 2):

The version `10.0.1.0.0-py2` clearly intended for Python2 only. BTW, where did you get such an old version. At the linked page at PyPI there is only 11.0.1.0.0 and 11.0.1.0.1 (and beta versions). Try version 11.0.1.0.1.

Comment: Can you send me the exact line to run through the terminal please@phd

Comment: If I enter pip3 install odoo11-addon-web-tree-dynamic-colored-field==11.0.1.0.1, it shows " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement odoo<11.1dev,>=11.0a (from odoo11-addon-web-tree-dynamic-colored-field==11.0.1.0.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for odoo<11.1dev,>=11.0a (from odoo11-addon-web-tree-dynamic-colored-field==11.0.1.0.1)"

Comment: [That](https://github.com/acsone/setuptools-odoo/blob/master/setuptools_odoo/core.py#L56) how they declare dependencies, but [odoo at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/odoo/#history) doesn't have version 11, it only has 1.0. Perhaps they install `odoo` from a different source, not from PyPI.

Comment: Found: [this is odoo 11.0](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/ad04c386484c0314930ac03515a07b682c413ab2/odoo/release.py#L15). `pip3 install 'git+https://github.com/odoo/odoo@staging.11.0#egg=odoo-11.0'`

Comment: will this satisfy my question?

Comment: The repository is rather large and `pip` is eager to clone it entirely which is slow. I recommend to clone it faster manually and install from the local clone: `git clone -b staging.11.0 --depth 1 --single-branch https://github.com/odoo/odoo && cd odoo && pip install .`